# Additional condition to guarantee continuity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Suppose that $f : X \rightarrow Y, g : Y \rightarrow Z$ be functions.
If $g \circ f$ and $g$ are continuous, d must $f$  be continuous ?
(I think No, like if $g$ is a constant function)

Is there any condition A that forces $f$ to be continuous ?

Like if $ g \circ f $ and $g$ are continuous and (A) satisfies, then $f$ is continuous ?
(I guess like if any open set of $O$ of $Y$, there is an open set $U$ of $Z$ such that $O = g^{-1}(U)$, then $f$ must be continuous?.
Can it get more practical ? Easier condition for additional condition (A) etc)

Comment: If $Y$ is compact, $Z$ is Hausdorff, and $g$ is monic, you get $f$ is continuous. You definitely need $g$ to be monic (also called “one-to-one”) in most instances.

Comment: Do you have a proof of such statement ?

Comment: There is a theorem which says if $g:Y\to W$ is a continuous bijection with $Y$ compact and $W$ Hausdorff, then $g$ is a homeomorphism, and thus has a continuous inverse. No, our $g:Y\to Z$ is not a bijection in my statement above, but we can take $W=f(Y).$ Since $W$ is a subspace of a Hausdorff space, it is Hausdorff, and $g:Y\to W$ has a continuous inverse. Then $f=g^{-1}\circ(g\circ f)$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$

If $g\circ f:X\to Z $ continuous and $g$ is an injective open map, then $f$ is continuous.

Proof: Let $U\in \tau_Y$ , then $g(U) \in\tau_Z$ as $g$ is an open map.

Now by continuity of $g\circ f$ ,

$(g\circ f) ^{-1}(g(U) \in \tau_X$

$f^{-1}(g^{-1}(g(U)) \in \tau_X$

Now injectivity of $g$ forces $f^{-1}(U) \in\tau_X$

Hence $f$ is continuous.

This result also true if $g$ is a closed map.

---

Given $g$ is continuous. We know any continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a closed  map.

$A\subset Y$ closed $\implies$ $A$ is compact $\implies$$g(A) \subset Z$ compact $\implies $ $ g(A) \subset Z$ closed.

1. Closed subset of a compact space is compact.
2. Continuous image of a compact set is compact.
3. Compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed.

---

Hence it is enough to assume $Y$ is compact and $Z$ is Hausdorff with the injectivity of $g$ to imply the continuity of $f$.